# what is gr:get:User in Facebook Graph Api? Application Limit Reached Error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have an app using facebook's javascript and c# sdk.  One day I was getting the `error 4 : Application request limit reached.` In the facebook app dashboard I see this.

```
Too Many Calls  - 1 hour, 50 minutes

Method                         Fraction of Budget
gr:get:User                     115%
gr:get:Post/likes               6.3%
gr:get:User/likes               0.26%
gr:post:Event/attending         0.05%
ui:permissions.request:popup:p  0.01%
ui:feed:iframe:post:            0.01%
gr:get:/schema                  0%
ui:permissions.request:async:g  0%
```

I'm assuming that in  `gr:get:User` the "gr" means graph.  then `get:User`  I guess has to be limited to calls from the javascript sdk of

```
FB.api('/me', function (data) { ...
```

will logging the user in from javascript sdk also make an identical `get:User` call ????

```
 FB.login(function (response) { .......
```

are these to only to ways to add to the gr:get:User calls??  Is it maybe that get:User is a sum of all get:Likes + get:Posts + get:Friends ??  This doesn't seem to make sense that we are hitting the limit of get User requests.

we do have some pages that have up to 40 likes on a single page , right now we have it (not a good way to do it, and will be changed) where we are using `<fb:Like ...` to render these like buttons, and next to *each* like action we have

```
        $(function () {
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=@ConfigSettings.FacebookAppId";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

so that means for each like button there is an ajax call for facebook and also for the time being it is making up to 40 calls to get all.js file from facebook.  Do these count as gr:get:User calls?? and can they be adding to the number of calls that is hitting the limit?

**update**

The reason I ask what calls from our code are triggering the gr:get:user is because as far as I can see it looks like a malicious user trying to log in repeatedly. I am just looking for confirmation that there is not other graph api calls can can add to the gr:get:User count.

When we make the call to login the user from javascript sdk all that you send is your app id, so I can not set different access tokens.  once the user is logged in , then we do use the user auth token

**update again**

We have gotten the `error 4 : Application request limit reached.` again , this is being thrown any time any user tries to make any calls to facebook from this app.  It is not a per (user , app) error.  Any body have any clue what is causing this or how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are right, each Like button makes request to user info, to show friends who already liked this page.

I think you can try to **insert Like buttons via facebook js sdk** and **only after you've loaded all.js script**. In this case you will avoid extra requests of all.js and you also will avoid extra request of user info, because it will be cached on client side by js sdk.